# dplyr in package creation: group_by with string without group_by_

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, nse

I am currently developing a package in which I try to implement a function that internally uses `dplyr::group_by`. However, upon package checking (devtools CRAN checks), I get a NOTE stating that `no visible binding for global variable Levels`.

```r
foo <- function(x) {
  out <- data.frame(Levels = x) %>%
    group_by(Levels) %>%
    summarise(n = n())
   return(out)
}
```

```
foo: no visible binding for global variable 'Levels'
  Undefined global functions or variables:
    Levels
```

In order to do it in a non-NSE fashion, I could use `group_by_()` with a string, but I understood that this way of doing this is deprecated, in favour of the use of quosures. However, I still have trouble figuring out how to do it.

I tried using `one_of()`, without success:

```r
foo <- function(x) {
  table_full <- data.frame(Levels = x) %>%
    group_by(one_of("Levels")) %>%
    summarise(n = n())
}
```

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: No tidyselect variables were registered
```

What would be the most correct way of achieving that?

Comment: Exactly what did you do to get that error message?

Comment: Do you have some data that we can work with?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. Aside from the fact that `foo` as it is written does not return anything, everything is fine. If I add `return(table_full)` as the last line of `foo`, `foo(mtcars$gear)` gives the expected result.

Comment: try `dplyr::summarise` instead of just summarise

Comment: Like @MauritsEvers I'm unable to reproduce. I'd consider restarting your session and try again.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify that the NOTE message appears in the context of package CRAN-checking, that doesn't like Non-Standart Evaluation

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something or couldn't you do:

```
library(dplyr)

foo <- function(x) {
  data.frame(Levels = x) %>%
    group_by(Levels) %>%
    summarise(n = n())
}

foo(mtcars$gear)
```

which results in:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Levels     n
   <dbl> <int>
1     3.    15
2     4.    12
3     5.     5
```